# How to consume NPM packages in the browser with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, npm, typescript

This is my setup:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/lodash/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {'js': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
        });

        System
            .import('./js/app')
            .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**

```
import {_} from 'lodash';

export class App {};
```

When I try transpiling TypeScript into JavaScript I get the error below:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'lodash'.
```

What's the most standard/recommended way of loading a NPM packing into your project when using TypeScript?

**Notes**

- `node_modules` is accessible and the file `node_modules/lodash/index.js` is being served correctly.
- I'm trying not to use `Bower` because I find it should be done with `NPM` instead.
- I'm using `SystemJS` which I believe is an universal module loader.

Comment: For starters, even if your node_modules directory is accessible, I think commonly a separate set of clientside packages is used via something like Bower (which is, itself, an NPM package). Secondly, you may need to load a dependency manager like commonjs or requirejs before other scripts in a browser, while import support is built straight into Node.

Comment: Hi @Katana314 thanks for your comment. See my answer under "Notes".

Comment: "*I find it should be done with NPM instead.*" - can you explain this reasoning further? I should note that my node_modules directory tends to contain lots of files that absolutely don't make sense to be publically served, and the same may be true of you.

Comment: I agree that the `node_modules` can get bloated very easily with both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`. But then I'd use a `Gulp` task to select, concat and inject only what I need into the `index.html` for production.

Answer (score 0):

First off, typescript can't find your module because you need to put the typings in your file. Second, you need to export your typescript using the --module system flag (or equivalent in tsconfig.json). And third it needs to be loaded using systemjs. I would highly recommend you use JSPM for this, I know I know - another package manager, but it's more of an extension on NPM than anything else. It allows you to manage your Systemjs deps really easily. http://jspm.io/

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I'm not famililar with SystemJs, but from what I know of module loaders, they recognize libraries by *the path they were loaded from*, not the module's global name or anything. So, having lodash loaded via a `<script>` won't actually help it know whether or not it has it, or what object to give back. In basic terms, you'll want to load it via your module loader, not on its own.

However, you likely don't want to write "*../node_modules/*" into all your require statements in-script; that'd be annoying. You could look through SystemJs' configuration documentation to see if there's a way to create a mapping, so that a particular module name will automatically cause it to know to use a certain path for the script.